# change specific pixel color via fragment/pixel shader?(opengl)

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, pixel-shader

Is there any way to change specific pixel color via fragment/pixel shader? (like a uniform variable?)

To be specific, im trying to implement ray-traced shadows.

Comment: This question is too unclear. Where exactly lies the problem? In changing the color of a fragment, or in setting the specific pixel? A specific pixel of what: The backbuffer? A framebuffer texture?

Comment: Setting the specific pixel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *pixel* you mean an actual pixel on the screen, then you can achieve that with multistage rendering. Render your scene to an FBO (to a texture), then render the quad onto a screen with that texture.

If the FBO texture size will be exactly the same as screen size, every invocation of the fragment shader will nicely correspond to the screen position.